# Kotlin local function with generic

Tags: kotlin, generics, functional-programming

I'm just fooling around with some Functional Programming techniques and tried to implement a generic drop function for a list. However it seems the types are getting shadowed. I'm wondering why I can't re-use a generic type declared.

The IDE doesn't want me to reuse the generic type

```
sealed class List<out A> {
  
    fun <A> drop(n: Int): List<A> {
        fun go(n: Int, l: List<A>): List<A> = when (n) {
                0 -> l
                else -> go(n - 1, l.tail())
        }
        return go(n, this)
    }
}
```

The IDE says the following

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
List<A#1 (type parameter of chapter3.List.drop)>
Found:
List<A#2 (type parameter of chapter3.List)>
```

Is this not possible with inner local functions?

Comment: I think you should move your `drop` function out of the companion object, and remove the `<A>` type parameter from it because it's already defined in `List<out A>`. When you are doing `go(n, this)` inside `drop`, `this` is referring to the companion object, not your list.

Comment: Argh- it actually is outside of the companion object. I was trying to remove non-related functions before posting my question.  Still same error though :/

Comment: You still haven't removed the `<A>` from `drop`. You are defining a new generic `A`-type that is not the same as the one in `List<out A>`.

Comment: Thank you! This was it.

```
    fun drop(n: Int): List<A> {
        fun go(n: Int, l: List<A>): List<A> = when (n) {
            0 -> l
            else -> go(n - 1, l.tail())
        }
        return go(n, this)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to redefine you A type again in the function, it cames from the sealed class

```
sealed class List<out A> {


fun drop(n: Int): List<A> {
    fun go(n: Int, l: List<A>): List<A> = when (n) {
            0 -> l
            else -> go(n - 1, l.tail())
    }
    return go(n, this)
}
}
```